# Windows Firewall whitelisting applications

Tags: windows, networking, security, firewall, windows-firewall

I'm having a few difficulties setting up my office computers.
I am trying to block all programs from accessing the internet, with a few exceptions:

**1) Web browsers should be able to access only a couple of websites.**

**2) TeamViewer should work properly.**

I tried setting the default for outbound rules to block all the connections and after that I added "allow" rules for TeamViewer and for the browsers to be able to access certain websites (added websites IP's using a custom rule).

However, the "Allow" rules do not seem to work, giving me no access to the internet at all. What seems to be the problem here?

**EDIT:** I'd love to know why does allowing program, such as a TeamViewer the standard way (Add outbound rule => Rule for a program => select the program path) does not provide access for the program to the internet, but adding a custom rule with unblocking TCP/UDP port for it does work. Theres should be no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points:

Do not use TCP 80 for teamviewer

> TCP/UDP Port 5938: TeamViewer prefers to make outbound TCP and UDP
>   connections over port 5938 – this is the primary port it uses, and
>   TeamViewer performs best using this port. Your firewall should allow
>   this at a minimum.

[See this.](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer/ta-p/4139)

You would be better off setting this all on one central firewall than using every workstations' windows firewall.

I think you can configure the http and https protocols using one allow rule. But windows firewall rule would allow / deny IP address not a host name.  You can achieve better results using HOSTS file. Again windows firewall is not the best tool for this task. See [this link](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/07/how-to-use-group-policy-to-allow-or-block-ur).

It is not enough to allow teamviewer.exe through firewall, minimum [is this](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-12/Unable-to-connect-to-TeamViewer-ID-LAN-only/td-p/6271):

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "!Allow Outbound 5938 UDP TeamViewer.exe Local Port" -Enabled True -Direction Outbound -Profile ANY -LocalPort 5938 -RemotePort ANY -Protocol UDP -Program "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe" -Action Allow -Description "Allows Outbound TeamViewer.exe communication via 5938 UDP."
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "!Allow Outbound UDP svchost.exe" -Enabled True -Direction Outbound -Profile ANY -Protocol UDP -Program "C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe" -Action Allow -Description "Allows Outbound UDP svchost.exe."
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "!Allow Outbound TCP TeamViewer.exe" -Enabled True -Direction Outbound -Profile ANY -Protocol TCP -Program "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe" -Action Allow -Description "Allows Outbound TCP TeamViewer.exe."
```

Teamviewer.exe is not the only process comunicating over network. There may be other processes like `TeamViewer_Service.exe` or `svchost.exe` that need to make outbound TCP connections. See [TcpView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) for more info.

In case 5938 is blocked on any other firewall in the way, you can still use 443 for TeamViewer.

Comment: This solution is not suitable for me because it only configures Internet Explorer browser. Besides, denying an IP adress instead of a domain does not seem to be a problem for me.

Comment: @aurimas The main point is that you should create two allow rules - one for teamviewer and one for http.

Comment: @Vojtech Already did that, but it doesn't seem to work properly. Please read the edit section, help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Vojtech, How would one know what else an application requires to function properly over the network, besides allowing the standard "*.exe" of the program? Provided from your answer, TW also needs allowed svchost process. Besides that, Your answer is sufficient, thank you.